# My web application is showing different output when deployed on Heroku, why so?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, weather-api

I made a Weather application which shows the weather for 4 days starting from today.The web application performs as expected when I am testing on localhost and I am getting perfect results,i.e If today is the date 15 August 2020 so when I search my city I get the weather for 15 August then 16th,17th and 18th August. But when I deploy my app on Heroku I am getting the weather starting from 16th August,17th,18th and 19th of August. Can anyone point out my mistake ? Thanks in advance. 
Below is my code in app.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const https = require("https");

// done requiring module
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var daysArray = [];
const imgUrl = [];
var imgUrlSingle = "";

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 4000;
}
app.listen(port, function (res) {
  console.log("Port started successfully at host 4000");
});
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index");
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const cityName = req.body.cityName;
  //   res.render("forecast");
  const url =
    "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +
    cityName +
    "&appid=" +
    process.env.WEATHER_API +
    "&units=metric&cnt=32";
  https.get(url, function (response) {
    response.on("data", function (data) {
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const time = new Date().getHours();
      weatherData.list.forEach(function (single) {
        var textHour = single.dt_txt.substring(11, 13);
        var numberHour = parseInt(textHour, 10);
        var difference = Math.abs(time - numberHour);
        if (
          difference === 1 ||
          difference === 0 ||
          (time === 23 && numberHour === 21) ||
          (time === 24 && numberHour === 0) ||
          (time === 2 && numberHour === 00)
        ) {
          daysArray.push(single);
          imgUrlSingle =
            "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" +
            single.weather[0].icon +
            ".png";
          imgUrl.push(imgUrlSingle);
        }
      });
      // res.send(daysArray);
      res.render("forecast", { daysArray: daysArray, imgUrl: imgUrl });
      daysArray = [];
    });
  });
});
```

The code in my forecast.ejs is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Weather Forecast</title>

    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Google Fonts  -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&amp;family=
  Montserrat:wght@500;900&amp;display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
        
      <div class="row">
        <% daysArray.forEach(function(singleDay,index){ %>
        <div class="col-6 col-me d-lg-none">
          <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
                <%= singleDay.dt_txt.substring(0,10) %>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">
                <img
                  src= <%= imgUrl[index] %>
                />
              </h1>
              <p class="description">
                <%= singleDay.weather[0].description %> <br />
                <%= singleDay.main.temp %> &#8451
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- For desktop -->

        <div class="col-lg-3 d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
                  <%= singleDay.dt_txt.substring(0,10) %>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">
                  <img
                    src= <%= imgUrl[index] %>
                  />
                </h1>
                <p class="description">
                  <%= singleDay.weather[0].description %> <br />
                  <%= singleDay.main.temp %> &#8451
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        <% }) %>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</html>
```

The code in index.ejs is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/docs/4.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Weather Forecast</title>

    <link
      rel="canonical"
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="CSS/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Google Fonts  -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&amp;family=
  Montserrat:wght@500;900&amp;display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">
    <form class="form-signin" action="/" method="POST">
      <img
        class="mb-4"
        src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg"
        alt=""
        width="72"
        height="72"
      />
      <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Enter you city</h1>
      <input
        name="cityName"
        type="cityName"
        id="inputEmail"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="City Name"
        required
        autofocus
      />

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>

      <p class="copyright">&copy; Raxy_45</p>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the Heroku server is in a different timezone.

Comment: Just a hunch.... i guess the Date.now returns the time of the server. And the server will be in a timezone different from ours.... so try solving that. To change the default timezone refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: Thank You, it worked for me . The solution is : Replace the code line ```const time = new Date().getHours();``` with ```var options = { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata", hour12: false };
      var date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", options);
      var time = parseInt(date.substring(11, 13));```. It works

Comment: But that's like implicitly giving the timezone (Indian timezone in my case), so How do I make the code more dynamic i.e. like whatever the location maybe say US for instance then depending upon the client's browser location the timezone must be updated dynamically in my code .